# Rolle-like problem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, rolles-theorem

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ a function that is  continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Prove that there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that
$$f'(c)\cdot \int\limits_a^c f(x) ~dx=-f^2(c).$$
This kind of problems usually reduces to find an appropriate function and to apply Rolle theorem for this function, in order to get the required equality. The obvious/easy choices did not get me there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true, as the example $a=0,b=1$ and $f(x)=x$ shows.

But if we have in addition that $f(b)=0$, then define

$g(x):= f(x)\int\limits_a^x f(t) ~dt$. Then $g(a)=g(b)=0$ and

$$g'(x)=f'(x)\int\limits_a^x f(t) ~dt+f(x)^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

You claim seems incorrect.
take $$f(x)=1$$
then
$$f(c)=0$$

Comment: Surely you meant $f'(c)=0$?

Comment: @Milten no. $ f(c)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to take $F'(x)=f(x)$ so:
$$F''(c)\left[F(c)-F(a)\right]=-\left[F'(c)\right]^2$$
now can such a point exist?